# Bedrock with MAMP can't install WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-bedrock

I have MAMP installed on my Mac with MacOS HighSierra 10.13.4.
I have ran `composer create-project roots/bedrock`in my `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`folder.

I have started up my servers via the MAMP UI. When I surf to `http://localhost:8888/MAMP`I get the MAMP startpage so everything seems to be working fine.

When I go to `http://localhost:8888/bedrock` I get a list of my files and dirs in my bedrock folder:

```
Index of /bedrock 
Parent Directory 
.env 
.env.example 
.gitignore  
CHANGELOG.md 
...
```

This is what my .env file looks like:

```
DB_NAME=adatabase
DB_USER=auser
DB_PASSWORD=apassword

# Optional variables
# DB_HOST=localhost
# DB_PREFIX=wp_

WP_ENV=development
WP_HOME=http://localhost:8888/bedrock
WP_SITEURL=${WP_HOME}/wp
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong since I don't see the WordPress installation page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `apache`, by dint of MAMP's default config, isn't serving from the correct directory for a bedrock project.

According to the [bedrock docs](https://roots.io/bedrock/docs/installing-bedrock/), you should:

> Set your site vhost document root to `/path/to/site/web/` (`/path/to/site/current/web/` if using deploys)

So, you'll need to modify your MAMP config to serve this project not from `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bedrock`, but from **`/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bedrock/web`**.

Comment: I have changed it as you said but I get an `404 Not found The requested URL /bedrock/wp/wp-admin/install.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: That's progress! It would appear that the error code is telling you exactly what it means; the file isn't there. I wonder if you could confirm what happens when you run `composer install` in the directory?

Comment: It says `Nothing to install or update` and I've checked the file is actualy there in the dir

Comment: Hmm.. hold on a second. "`bedrock`" shouldn't be in the URL path. Are you sure you've got the apache config correct? If you did as instructed above, that would indicate that the file being searched for is actually `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bedrock/web/bedrock/wp/wp-admin/install.php`... which almost certainly doesn't exist.

Comment: my project is in my bedrock folder this is what my path looks like `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bedrock/web`

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, I've removed the "/bedrock" from my .env file and when I surf to localhost i see the installer now! thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to click Set Web & MySQL ports to 80 & 3306 via MAMP > Preferences > Ports.

Then http://localhost/bedrock

Please let me know if this works :)